Can I use VPN(L2TP/IPsec) with strongSwan and xl2tpd on Google Compute Engine?
I couldn't find any questions about building on GCE, so I created a new question.
I tried to build this, but it was rejected by the error Couldn't open the /dev/ppp device: No such file or directory.
I know I can use Cloud VPN, but I want to keep the cost as low as possible.
